# Erase missing values in shiny

Tags: r, input, server, shiny

I've coded a shiny app. It reads any input data in csv format. I've also introduced a column selector to let the user select which columns he/she wants to analyze. My problem is that I want let the user also erase missing values but when the user click 'Erase missings' it reads the data again and don't respect variable selection user has done before.

So I don't know hot to separate both operations read input data and erase missings values.

Thanks in advance!!

```
data1<-reactive({ fichero<-input$fichero
#Si el fichero que leemos no tiene nada devolvemos un Nulo
if (is.null(fichero))
  {return()}
# Leemos el fichero
salida<-read.csv(fichero$datapath, header=input$header,              sep=input$sep,quote=input$quote,stringsAsFactors=input$stringAsFactors)
# Si marcamos la opción de no missings entonces solo se tienen en cuenta los      registros que no tienen ningun NA
# if (input$miss==TRUE) {salida<-salida[complete.cases(salida),]}
return(salida)
})

data<-reactive({ 
data1f<-data1()
salida<-data1f
# Si marcamos la opción de no missings entonces solo se tienen en cuenta los registros que no tienen ningun NA
if (input$miss==TRUE) {salida<-data1f[complete.cases(data1f),]}
return(salida)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me for not being able to read your comments, so I may not fully understand what you're trying to do. You also haven't provided a reproducible example so I've put together a skeleton `server.R` as a guide, not a fully functioning example

Your app reads the data each time because of this line

```
data1f<-data1()      ## this is a call to the reactive `data1` function every time `input$miss` is changed
```

One way you can preserve the data is to use [`reactiveValues()`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) and only overwrite it when the button is pressed.

So in `server.R` you would have something like

```
function(input, output, session) {

    reactive_values <- reactiveValues()
    reactive_values$salida_original <- NULL
    reactive_values$salida_changed <- NULL

    ##  ...

    ## Observe the button press
    observe({ 

        if(input$fichero){

            isolate({  ## To stop a dependancy on the other inputs$ you are calling
                salida<-read.csv(fichero$datapath, 
                                 header=input$header,              
                                 sep=input$sep,
                                 quote=input$quote,
                                 stringsAsFactors=input$stringAsFactors)    

                reactive_values$salida_original <- salida
                reactive_values$salida_changed <- salida

            })
        }
    })

    ## Now we have the data stored in a reactive_value, and can make changes to it as and when required
    ## without calling the 'read.csv' each time
    data <- reactive({
        salida_original <- reactive_values$salida_original   ## the untouched, original data
        salida_changed <- reactive_values$salida_changed     ## the data that gets changed each time
        if(input$miss) {
            ## Code to change the data here
            ## salida <- salida_changed[complete.cases(salida_changed), ]
        }

        ## update salida_changed 
        reactive_values$salida_changed <- salida             ## update the changed data as and when a change i srequired
        return(salida)

    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It totally works now!! I hadn't heard of reactive_values() till now.

Comment: @ManuelFcoAviles - no problem. reactive values are extremely useful. If this answers your question you should mark it as answered by pressing the 'tick' at the top-left of this answer

Comment: I can't press like button. it says I vae no enough reputation or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but I can't make your solution work. I've changed a few things because in the reactive piece of code it needs to know what happen if input$miss==0 so i write else {salida<-salida_original}. Also I've written fichero<-input$fichero in the observe code.At the end I keep having same problem. Onse i chek input$miss field it reloads the  file even if I've replaced some variables using an output$choose_columns object which it uses data(). Do you know what is happening?

Comment: @ManuelFcoAviles - are you able to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that I/someone else can run to see your issue? Otherwise it's hard to understand your problem

Comment: The code that works. data <- reactive({if (is.null(input$fichero)|| is.null(input$columns)) {salida_original <- reactive_values$salida_original    salida_changed <-reactive_values$salida_changed }  else {salida_original <- reactive_values$salida_original  salida_changed <- reactive_values$salida_changed salida_original<-salida_original[, input$columns, drop = FALSE] salida_changed<-salida_changed[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]} if(input$miss) {salida<-salida_changed[complete.cases(salida_changed),]} else {salida<-salida_original} reactive_values$salida_changed <- salida return(salida)})